# Updating Moodle that installed whitout git but update with git

Tags: git, moodle

Maybe this question little weird, but I can't find the good title to describe this problem.

let say my client downloaded the moodle 3.6 as zip file, they have install it and it working, latter on, they ask me to update the moodle to 3.9 for some reason.

I know moodle has the git repository, and they asked me to update it trough git, last time i checked there is no .git folder beacuse they not install it using git.

I'm trying to clone new moodle to another folder and then copy the .git folder to existing installed moodle, I'm trying to use git command and it work, but when I'm trying to use git pull command the respon allways `Already up to date.` and unable to update.

am I doing wrong ?
or it shouldn't use this way ?

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to clone new moodle to another folder

You could then simply rename the original folder as _old, and rename the cloned folder as your current moodle.

If you copy only `.git`, since it contains the latest clone history, any pull will consider everything was already... pulled.

The alternative is to llok at the delta with:

```
cd /current/moodle
git --git-dir=../path/to/new/cloned/repo status

# warning: this can override files:
git --git-dir=../path/to/new/cloned/repo restore -- .
```

Comment: let say i do this, what about old data? like plugins and themes, do I have to move them manually?

Comment: @KhairuAqsara In the first option of my answer, yes. In the second, no (but do a backup first)

Comment: Thanks it's worked, I just need to add `.git` at the end of `--git-dir` path.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) do db backup
2) backup your current directory and moodle-data directory
3) do side clone of requested branch to moodle-clone directory
git clone -b MOODLE_36_STABLE git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git moodle-clone
4) copy .git a .github directories to your current production directory
Then you can delete moodle-clone directory.

Turn Moodle maitenance mode ON

Run in the production directory:
5) git status
6) git fetch
7) git reset --hard HEAD
8) git merge @{u}
9) git status

Now you can see the list only not synced custom directories.
Check the site, if there is minor 3.6 update, you will need to update database.
Before upgrading to 3.9 check compatibility of aditional plugins.

10) Update to 3.9 latest version:
git branch -a                                               
git branch --track MOODLE_39_STABLE origin/MOODLE_39_STABLE    
git checkout MOODLE_39_STABLE                          
git remote update
git pull

Any custom plugins and config file should stay untouched.

Tested today, I had the similar situation. Real downtime is only a matter of minutes because you can prepare everything in advance.
Turn Moodle maintenance mode OFF.

More commands at https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Git_for_Administrators
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).